# javax.naming.ConfigurationException does not contain an IOR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, server, ejb, corba

I have a probleme when I run client code for an Ejb Bean

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory");
System.out.println("property"+prop.getProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY));
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http://localhost:9191");
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(prop);
System.out.println("ha context"+context);
System.out.println(context.getEnvironment());
Object o = context.lookup("Advisor");
System.out.println("object"+o);
AdviceHome adviceHome = (AdviceHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(o,AdviceHome.class);
System.out.println("ha adviceHome"+adviceHome);
Advice advice = adviceHome.create();
System.out.println("enfin notre chere advice"+advice.getAdvice());
```

> error: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: http://localhost:9191 does
>   not contain an IOR

Im using j2sdkee1.3.1 server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IOR file, what does it do, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087083/what-is-an-ior-file-what-does-it-do-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: j2sdkee 1.3.1 is at least 17 years old. You might want to consider using more recent technology.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes I agree with you but actually I learn J2EE from a book headfirst Ejb and for that I use j2sdkee 1.3.1 :)

Comment: A lot of technologies used in that version are no longer relevant today, for example EJB was changed significantly in later specifications...

Comment: can you suggest me a good book to learn EJB